# Set Environment storage path on Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Is there a way to set the environment storage path in Robolectric to a specific path on the filesystem on the machine the Android unit tests are running on?

**Edit:**
I have a large library of XML files I need to be able to read into memory for a particular class to be usable/testable. I'd like to be able to point the Robolectric environment storage path to the location of this library on my Mac so that I can read these files as if it were on an Android device.

Though I'm open to other methods of achieving the same result.

Comment: Can you share more details what are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to set the path in Robolectirc?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope that helps portray what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: how do you pass them in android app? Do you read them from assets, internal or external storage?

Comment: They get extracted from assets after app installation to external storage, where they remain as long as the app is installed. I'd rather not have to do that every time I run my unit tests as it slows testing. It would be much faster to be able to specify a location on my machine where these files already exist. Also would make it easier when I have to modify these  XML files. It possible to define the location of Environment.getExgternalStorageDirectory() to a specific location on the machine running unit tests or no?

Comment: The hacky solution would be in setup copy your XMLs into the directory which emulates external storage.

Comment: That's more or less what I'm currently doing as a workaround, except they're unzipped instead of just copied. Anyway I appreciate your help.